# Trying to mask video to SVG shape

Tags: css, svg, mask, clip

here is my css:

```
.svg-clipped {
    -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath);
    clip-path: url(#svgPath);
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1153.37 494"><g data-name="Layer 2"><clipPath id="svgPath"><path d="M1093.37 0H60A60 60 0 0 0 0 60v374a60 60 0 0 0 60 60l1033.37-179c39.28-6.29 60-26.86 60-60V60a60 60 0 0 0-60-60z" fill="#990000" fill-rule="evenodd" data-name="Layer 1"/></clipPath></g></svg>

<!--I can see this in the browser-->    
<img class="svg-clipped" style="margin: -500px 0 0 0;"  src="image.jpg" alt="" width="100%"/>

<!--I cannot see this in the browser-->
    <video class="svg-clipped" autoplay src="Video.mp4" style="margin: -500px 0 0 0; border: solid 3px #990000; width: 100%" ></video>
```

I'm trying to view the video in the shape of the svg, but i cannot get it to work. I can see the image that i have in my html in the shape of the svg fine, which im using just to test to ensure the clipping works, and will then remove once i get the video to work. Im not understanding what's going on.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What browser are you using? `clip-path` isn't fully supported on all browsers https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path Seems like it's working for me on Chrome.

Comment: hmm i see. I was using safari

Comment: how do i activate it in safari? what is the alternate rule?

Comment: There's no alternate property. Maybe try absolutely positioning an inverse of your svg over the video? So if your svg is a circle, in an svg editor put a white box around your circle and then cut the circle out of the box.